# Filter and import very huge xml (or csv)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, xml, csv

i have a very huge xml file (or csv I have both files), we are talking about millions products for a weight of 5/6GB.
From this catalogue I want create ad import in a table (mysql o sql server) only some brands.

I tried to import the entire catalog and then filter it, but the import processes stop because the file is too big!
How can I do?

Comment: First decide what RDBMS you want to use; importing data into a data base engine is almost always proprietary.

Comment: We can't guess what import process you're talking about, or why it stopped. XML and CSV are completely different file types. CSVs are very easy to import because each line is an independent record. XML is far trickier because there's no easy way to identify records. You have to keep reading and parsing until you find the end tag.

Comment: There's no `mysql or sql server` either. SQL Server has an entire ETL system, SSIS, that can read , transform and and stream data from multiple sources. MySQL doesn't.

Comment: Split it in many smaller files? easier with csv.

Comment: 5 or 6GiB isn't an extraordinarily large file in the grand scheme of ETL things. If you're running out of memory have you just tried to get more memory? (e.g.: scale up your instance size if you're in AWS or Azure.)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos SSIS can actually import data into a mysql server as well as long as a compatible mysql driver is available.

Comment: Didn't say it can't. It's still a SQL Server feature, requiring a SQL Server license. Setting up the correct MySQL driver can be a bit of a problem and true bulk imports need `LOAD DATA INFILE` which essentially copies the file to MySQL server's disks before doing a bulk import. There's no real streaming bulk insert mechanism

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers.
Let me explain in more detail what I am trying to do: I tried to import the icecat catalogue locally in xml via mysql workbench but I found out that there is an import limit.
Then I tried to bypass the problem with the LOAD DATA INFILE query but as the file was too big it was giving me memory problems. I cannot even open the file with excel.
Then I switched to sql server to see if I could import the file and solve the problem differently, but it still gives me memory problems.
Same with trying csv.

I don't need to import the whole catalogue, just a part of it, but I don't know how (and if it is possible) to filter an xml (or csv) before importing it, so as to create a table with only the records (rows and columns) of my interest.

Comment: Let's review CSV option only.  It is easier to deal with.  Please post first 100 lines of your CSV file.  Then we need to know column names / datatype for each column.  Then we need to know what makes a row or column eligible to be imported, please.

Comment: This is not an answer.